# Fourier transform: Why is it allowed to differentiate under the integral?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, klein-gordon-equation

If we want to solve the Klein-Gordon equation $(\Box+m^2)\phi=0$ we can use the Fourier transform:
$$\phi(x)=\int_\mathbb{R^4} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}kx}c_k\:\mathrm{d^4}k$$
Which gives:
$$(\Box+m^2)\phi(x)= \int_ \mathbb{R^4} (m^2-k^2)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}kx}c_k\:\mathrm{d^4}k=0 $$
My question is now why it’s allowed to commute differentiation and integration?
I know from the measure theory version of the Leibniz rule that it‘s possible when $(m^2-k^2)c_k\in L(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but that’s useless without knowing $c_k$.

Comment: [It depends on certain conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Proof_of_basic_form).

Comment: @J.G. but how do I know that this conditions are satisfied?

Comment: Hint: you only need $c_ke^{-ikx}$ and its derivatives to be continuous in $k$ and $x$. Now defer to a physicist on the relevant implications for the $c_k$.

Comment: @J.G. but as far as I know that is only valid if we integrate over a compact set.

Comment: Ah, that. Well, physics also takes the functions as decaying too rapidly at infinity for the use of a non-compact integration range to be a problem.

Comment: @J.G. so does that mean in mathematics that cannot be justified and in physics we assume that the support is compact?

Comment: You do not need compact support to differentiate under the integral! You might be interested by looking at the theory of distributions. This allows the functions to be much worse

Comment: @LL3.14 do you have a reference for the sufficient conditions to differentiate under the integral sign that are here fulfilled?

Comment: The general definition of the Fourier transform is not as an integral but by duality. Then it can be defined for any tempered distribution, which includes any locally integrable function with polynomial growth for example. Then the fact that the derivative of the Fourier transform yields a multiplication by $(ik)$ in your convention holds for any tempered distribution. See any good course on distribution theory ... for example https://web.abo.fi/fak/mnf/mate/kurser/fourieranalys/chap3.pdf , second equation of Theorem 3.31